# How to prove that any closed path is homotopic to a point implies simply connected

Tags: complex-analysis

I am doing an exercise of complex analysis: prove that a **star-shaped** open set is simply connected.
And I have get that any closed path contained in it is homotopic to a point. But I am floored that why this is equivalent to any two paths with the same end points are homotopic(the definition of simply connected in the book I am reading）

Comment: Take two paths with the same end points and concatenate them to get a loop.

Comment: @LukasKofler  If I take two paths with the same end points $\gamma_1$  ,$\gamma_2$, then $\gamma_1 * \gamma_2^{-1}$ is a loop ,so how can I get $\gamma_1 * \gamma_2^{-1}$is homotopic to a point by $\gamma_1$ is homotopic  to $\gamma_2$,thanks!

Comment: We have $\gamma_1 * \gamma_2^{-1} \simeq 1 \simeq \gamma_1$.